# Young adult novel about a girl who has false memories of a human childhood, but was stolen from the woods to be experimented on

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult, dystopia

I read this book when I was quite young, maybe 12 years old (2013).

I remember it was about a girl who grew up in a futuristic society. This society’s government guards people from the woods/forest outside the gates.

The main girl meets this alien forest boy who has translucent, blue-ish skin with black hair. If I remember correctly, he comes from the woods where all the creatures like him have that ghastly appearance. They are deemed dangerous by the government. The girl and the boy meet, and she senses something familiar about him. Over time, they get to know each other despite his language being far different than hers, they become friends. I believe he is captured at some point to be tested and tortured by the lab scientists in the society.

Near the end of the book, the girl realizes she was stolen from the woods to be experimented on. She was forced to forget who she really was and turned human with false memories of a human childhood. The boy was her friend who went looking for her or went rescuing her. He would send her messages telepathically, but she assumed they weren’t real.

Sound familiar to anyone? I remember that the cover of the book was the side profile of one of the humanoid creatures.

Comment: Sounds very much like Keeper of the Isis Light by Monica Hughes. Though not sure of the cover.

Comment: Was the forest the other side of a ravine from the city, and you reached the forest by crossing a bridge over the ravine?

Comment: @Cassfrank No :( it’s not that one. Thank you for your effort, though!

Comment: @JohnRennie not sure about a ravine or a bridge. My memory of the story includes just the Forest being outside of a city/town that cannot access the forest.

Comment: sounds like a haddix novel, inc the side profile on the cover. maybe look at among the hidden series?